# MeteorJS Unexpected token import

Tags: meteor, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to write a Meteor package. I first created a meteor app using `meteor create myapp`, `cd` into the project root and did `meteor create --package mypkg`. This generated the base package boiler files. In the mainmodule entry JS file, I wrote

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
    require('./server/main.js');
}

if (Meteor.isClient) {
    require('./client/main.js');
}
```

In `client/main.js` I simply wrote

```
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
```

This causes an error when I run the application with `meteor`

```
W20180219-00:13:14.495(8)? (STDERR) import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';
W20180219-00:13:14.495(8)? (STDERR) ^^^^^^
W20180219-00:13:14.496(8)? (STDERR) 
W20180219-00:13:14.496(8)? (STDERR) SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
W20180219-00:13:14.496(8)? (STDERR)     at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
W20180219-00:13:14.496(8)? (STDERR)     at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
W20180219-00:13:14.496(8)? (STDERR)     at /home/user/Documents/GitHub/meteor-accounts-solutions/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:393:30
W20180219-00:13:14.496(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
W20180219-00:13:14.496(8)? (STDERR)     at /home/user/Documents/GitHub/meteor-accounts-solutions/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:220:19
W20180219-00:13:14.496(8)? (STDERR)     at /home/user/Documents/GitHub/meteor-accounts-solutions/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:471:5
W20180219-00:13:14.497(8)? (STDERR)     at Function.run (/home/user/Documents/GitHub/meteor-accounts-solutions/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/profile.js:510:12)
W20180219-00:13:14.497(8)? (STDERR)     at /home/user/Documents/GitHub/meteor-accounts-solutions/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:470:11
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

I have already included the following lines in `package.js`

```
api.versionsFrom('1.6.1');
    api.use([
        'ecmascript',
        'es5-shim',
        'babel-runtime'
    ]);
```

Any help appreciated. Please let me know if I should post more code, thank you.

Comment: How are you running your package to get this error?

Comment: I used meteor add myname:package, then run the project with meteor

Comment: It should work. Your mainModule is a bit weird though. Try `api.mainModule(&#39;client/main.js&#39;, &#39;client&#39;)` and `api.mainModule(&#39;server/main.js&#39;, &#39;server&#39;)` instead?

Comment: Sorry phone encoded the quotes, should be: `api.mainModule('client/main.js', 'client')` and `api.mainModule('server/main.js', 'server')`

Comment: @FredStark I tried your suggestion and it works, thank you. Weird cuz I am trying to mainmodule a shared JS entry, then using Meteor.isServer and isClient to import other files for server and client. Somehow my method doesn't work.